# GCM Push Notification Implementation

Tags: java, android, python, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I seem to be having trouble implementing push notifications using the basic GCM packages in my application.  I have tried several tutorials and have so-far been unable to get it working.

I was hoping that maybe I can get some help, when I send from a Ubuntu server I receive no notification.

MainActivity

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    private String RegID    = "";

    private Context context          = null;
    private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = null;
    private InstanceID instanceID    = null;
    private BroadcastReceiver mHandleMesageReceiver;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        if(RegID.isEmpty())
        {
            register RegInBG = new register();
            RegInBG.execute("e");

            post task = new post();
            task.execute(RegID);
            mHandleMesageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                }
            };
        }

    }


    /*Runnable task to be used to register
      app in the GCM service for push
      notifications, made by Devin Adams
     */
   
    public class register extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                if (instanceID == null) {
                    instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(context);
                }
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                RegID = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.sender_id), gcm.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                Log.e("***********", "************");
                Log.e("***********", "************");
                Log.e("RegID", RegID);
                Log.e("***********", "************");
                Log.e("***********", "************");
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Log.e("***********", "************");
                Log.e("***********", "************");
                Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
                Log.e("***********", "************");
                Log.e("***********", "************");
            }
            return "sd";
        }
    }


    public class post extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                String tempurl = getString(R.string.server_url);
                Uri.Builder b = Uri.parse(tempurl).buildUpon();
                String url = b.build().toString();
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(url))).openConnection();

                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.connect();

                connection.getOutputStream().write((params[0]).getBytes());
                connection.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
            }

            return "getg";
        }
    }

}
```

MyGcmListener

```js
 
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;
public class MyGcmListener extends GcmListenerService
{
    private static final String TAG = "International Studies";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data)
    {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
        Log.e("Message", "received ");

        sendNotification(message);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String message)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("International Studies")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

MyGcmMessageHandler

```js
 
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import java.lang.Runnable;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;


public class MyGCMMessageHandler extends IntentService {
    String mes;
    private Handler handler;

    public MyGCMMessageHandler()
    {
        super("MyGCMMessageHandler");
    }

    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        this.handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void close() {

            }

            @Override
            public void flush() {

            }

            @Override
            public void publish(LogRecord record) {

            }
        };
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        this.mes = extras.getString("title");
        this.showToast();
        Log.i("GCM", "Received: (" + messageType + ") " + mes);
        MyGCMReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    public void showToast()
    {
        this.handler.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MyGCMMessageHandler.this.getApplicationContext(), MyGCMMessageHandler.this.mes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the push script is run using python-gcm

```
from gcm import *
gcm = GCM("")
data = {'message': 'This is a test push', 'param2': 'value2'}
reg_id = ''
gcm.plaintext_request(registration_id=reg_id, data=data)
```

with the GCM being filled with the API key and reg_id my phone's reg_id in this application.

Can anyone help me out? I can't figure out what's wrong.

EDIT: Manifest.

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="abdroid.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="edu.csusb.internationalstudies" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".MyGcmListener" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code but still the all important manifest is missing! Please add the *relevent sections* only of the manifest and also see if you can trim the code a bit. You are doing a lot of logging. What do they tell you?

Comment: I get the RegID but no message notification logged out.

Comment: Unless I am very much mistaken this should be your actual package <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />

Comment: alright I changed it to the package name, now under MyGcmMessageHandler it says "cannot find symbol method post(<anonymous Runnable>)

Comment: that is a different question. Are you sure you have got the right imports for Handler and Runnable?

Comment: I added the imports for that class but I believe that I have the correct ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1: Your AndroidManifest.xml has the wrong settings. THis line should be changed.

```
<category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />
```

gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart should be replaced with your own package.

Problem number 2:
You have the wrong imports.

```
import java.util.logging.Handler;
```

Is not what you want. What's required is [android.os.Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable))

> There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and
>   runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to
>   enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

Comment: Alright, having fixed those two issues I'm still not getting any notifications when I push one.

Comment: Please accept this answer and post a new question (it solves not one but two different problems!) . In that question include the relevent log messages, and also include the result from your server side code.

Comment: Like I said, I get no logs from the message handler class, so there wouldn't be much in terms of logs and no feedback form the server.

Comment: You need to look at your server side script that sends the GCM now.